# Python, Split a string by whitespaces, similar to awk

Tags: python

I need to split the string based on whitespaces:

```
mystring = ['1      SLES11 SP1 64bit            [datastore1] SLES11 SP1 64bit/SLES11 SP1 64bit.vmx   sles11_64Guest          vmx-08  ']
#Removes white spaces
mystring.strip()
```

I want to achieve, similar to awk output :

```
# awk '{print $1, $2}' mystring
1 SLES11 SP1 64bit
```

I need to push the output similar to awk to array and read data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see that you have found `.split()`. What problems do you have?

Comment: @MagnusHoff: He has found `.strip()`, not `.split()`. And he obviously doesn't want to split on every single whitespace.

Comment: Your code is invalid. It needs to be `mystring[0].strip()`. Also, your requirements for splitting are a tad unclear. What *exactly*  are your criteria for splitting?

Comment: Looks like you are interested output of command. Also noticed that mystring is actually a one element list. And use split as @MagnusHoff suggested. strip is not required.

`print ' '.join(mystring.split())`

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Hah, thanks. I misread.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: It shouldn't matter how many characters of whitespace he has. `"this____splits".split()` should still return `['this', 'splits']` (underscores represent whitespace since SO doesn't display the extra whitespace)

Comment: @JoelCornett: Yes, it does to him: In his question, the first match (`$1`) is `1`, the second match (`$2`) is `SLES11 SP1 64bit`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Oh ok, I missed that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to split on *two or more*  whitespace characters?

```
>>> mystring = ['1      SLES11 SP1 64bit            [datastore1] SLES11 SP1 64bit/SLES11 SP1 64bit.vmx   sles11_64Guest          vmx-08  ']
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r"\s{2,}", mystring[0].strip())
['1', 'SLES11 SP1 64bit', '[datastore1] SLES11 SP1 64bit/SLES11 SP1 64bit.vmx',
'sles11_64Guest', 'vmx-08']
```

Answer (score 0):

Without regular expressions:

```
>>> mystring = '1      SLES11 SP1 64bit            [datastore1] SLES11 SP1 64bit/SLES11 SP1 64bit.vmx   sles11_64Guest          vmx-08  '
>>> a, dummy, c = mystring.partition("  ")
>>> print(a, c.lstrip().partition("  ")[0])
1 SLES11 SP1 64bit
```